# DataRow Deleting in DataGridView and attaching to DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, delete-row, errorprovider

I am deleting a row in DataGridView and this Datgridview is bind to a datatable (dt). After deleting the row. The data of that row in the data table is deleted and showing errors.

Comment: Your code would be helpful. Are you using update, accept, refresh commands and alike on your dataset and gridview?

Comment: Maybe clearing the content and rebinding the DataTable (rerun the query) can solve your problem.

Comment: if i rebind the data to that datatable cannot clear the error @ChristianMark

Comment: We cannot at assign a error for a particular datarow in datatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several way to accomplish this. One quick way is to create a data view instance out of the modified data table (data table after delete) and then call ToTable() method on that dataview. This will give us the original data.

```
DataView view= new DataView(yourTable, null, null, DataViewRowState.Deleted);
DataTable resultTable = view.ToTable();
```

Another approach would be

```
var rows=YourTable.Select(); // I assume your name of the table as YourTable and you can change it the way you want

foreach(var row in rows)
{
  if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
{
   var splr_Cntctnm = (string)row["splr_Cntctnm", DataRowVersion.Original];
   //you can access all deleted field information as above
}

}
```

Comment: where are you selecting the datarow

Comment: You don't need to supply any select statement in my first approach since data view will automatically extract all rows those are deleted and create a result table with all deleted rows.

Comment: what do you mean by rowerror ? If you talking about the error symbol in data table screenshot then that is not error rather that how deleted row will be represented in the debugger when you inspect the data table. I recommand you to read some fundamentals about row state especially DataRowState enum and how it is associated with different state of the data rows in any given data table. Ref 1: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx, Ref 2:http://www.dotnetfunda.com/codes/code1375-how-to-access-deleted-rows-in-datatabledataset.aspx